# Text in Visual Studio 2010 GroupBox?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I try to write a '&' sign for the title of the GroupBox I get a '_'. Why is it like this and how can I do to get a '&'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a double-ampersand, so '&&' instead of '&'.  (& is reserved character used for keyboard shortcuts)

Comment: In particular, `&` underlines the next character, which in the OP's case was probably a space. So `Foo & Bar` would show up as `Foo _Bar`.